# Apply a class in a Framer Motion tag, animate or initial prop

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

How do I use a Framer Motion tag, and in the `animate` and `initial` props, Apply a class.
Like so.

```
<motion.div
  initial={{ className: 'hidden' }}
  animate={{ className: 'visible' }}
>
  <div>yo</div>
</motion.div>
```

I **HAVE** to use classes as I am using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/).

I expect and hope there is a way to do this, 'cus the example I showed above, Just puts this in the rendered HTML tag `style="class-name:{class_name}"` which does absolutely nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla js with event

> onAnimationStart()

and

> onAnimationComplate()

then do your logic. References https://www.framer.com/docs/component/###onanimationstart

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control only visibility, you can play with css attributes like

```js
<motion.div
  initial={{ display: "none" }}
  animate={{ display: "block" }}
>
  <div>yo</div>
</motion.div>
```

However, there you can do more things with callback functions and javascript selectors as @Arfan mentioned:

```js
  function onStart() {
    document.getElementById("target")?.classList.add("visible");
    document.getElementById("target")?.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
  function onEnd() {
    document.getElementById("target")?.classList.remove("visible");
    document.getElementById("target")?.classList.add("hidden");
  }
...
<motion.div
  initial="rest"
  animate="anim"
  onAnimationStart={onStart}
  onAnimationComplate={onEnd}
  id="target"
>
  <div>yo</div>
</motion.div>
```